# how to properly insert into quickbase via Curl in php

Tags: php, quickbase

I created table with the following 3 fields with quickbase

**name,email,post**

Now am  trying to insert into the table via table id with quickbase.

here is the documentation API Link
[API lINK](https://developer.quickbase.com/operation/upsert)

**here is the API Curl documentation**

```
curl -X POST 'https://api.quickbase.com/v1/records' \
-H 'QB-Realm-Hostname: {QB-Realm-Hostname}' \
-H 'User-Agent: {User-Agent}' \
-H 'Authorization: {Authorization}' \
-d {}
```

**here is the sample request**

```
{
  "to": "bck7gp3q2",
  "data": [
    {
      "6": {
        "value": "This is my text"
      },
      "7": {
        "value": 10
      },
      "8": {
        "value": "2019-12-18T08:00:00.000Z"
      },
      "9": {
        "value": [
          "a",
          "b"
        ]
      },
      "10": {
        "value": true
      },
      "11": {
        "value": "user@quickbase.com"
      },
      "12": {
        "value": "www.quickbase.com"
      },
      "13": {
        "value": [
          {
            "id": "123456.ab1s"
          },
          {
            "id": "254789.mkgp"
          },
          {
            "id": "789654.vc2s"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "fieldsToReturn": [
    6,
    7,
    8,
    9,
    10,
    11,
    12,
    13
  ]
}
```

**Here is my effort so far**
When I run the code below, I have the following error

```
{"data":[],"metadata":{"createdRecordIds":[],"lineErrors":{"1":["Can not find record by ID \"My First post\"."]},"totalNumberOfRecordsProcessed":1,"unchangedRecordIds":[],"updatedRecordIds":[]}}{"data":[],"metadata":{"createdRecordIds":[],"lineErrors":{"1":["Can not find record by ID \"My First post\"."]},"totalNumberOfRecordsProcessed":1,"unchangedRecordIds":[],"updatedRecordIds":[]}}
```

**here is my code**

```
<?php

$access_t ="my_access_token-goes here";
$url="https://api.quickbase.com/v1/records";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$useragent ='my-user-agent goes here';

$quicbase_domain= 'my-quickbase-domain-goes-here';

$data='

{
  "to": "my-table-id-goes-here",
  "data": [
    {


      "1": {
        "value": "nancy more"
      },
      "2": {
        "value": "nancy@gmail.com"
      },

"3": {
        "value": "My First post"
      }

    }
  ]
  
}

';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
"QB-Realm-Hostname: quicbase_domain",
"User-Agent: $useragent",
"Authorization: QB-USER-TOKEN $access_t",
'Content-Type:application/json'
));  

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,'POST');
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,0);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 echo $response = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

print_r($response);
```

Comment: And what's your question about this? Having an error is fine, how did you try to resolve it?

Comment: Your question is not clear at all

Comment: I don't get that syntax at all. I mean the error is saying the record doesn't exist... So pretty sure that insert syntax is off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same endpoint is used for both insert and update and Quick Base uses the inclusion of the key field to distinguish between the two.  In my experience field ID #3 has always been the "Record ID#" field; one of the fields Quick Base automatically creates for every new table and the one it uses as the default key field.  Since your data array contains a value for field ID #3, Quick Base is interpreting your request as an update to which it can find no record with the ID "My First Post".  There's also the issue that field ID #3 expects a number, but Quick Base's error response is not sophisticated enough to give that feedback.

I think the issue with your request is that you have the wrong field IDs.  1, 2, and 3 correspond to the automatically generated fields of "Date Created", "Date Modified", and "Record ID#".  The fields that you created for your table probably start at field ID #6.  If you go into Quick Base and look at the properties of your table you should be able to see a list of fields and their Field Ids (if you don't see the Field Id column, you can choose to display it in Advanced Options).  Use the correct field IDs in your request, and it should work as expected.

Comment: This is what I was going to suggest also.

Comment: Thanks @Nathan Hawe. Insert is working now. before i accept your answer please do you have any idea on how I can delete  a particular row based on Id. Lets assume i want to delete record where an id is **18**. I have tried it like this but it says error **bad request** `$post ='
{
  "from": "bqvieybn",
  "where": "{18}"
}
';`

Comment: Thanks @Erich Wehrmann for responding also. Please do you have any idea on how I can delete data based on id as I stated in the comment section above.

Comment: @NancyMooree, you pass a query to delete.  So, assuming that in your example 18 is the record ID you would delete with `$post ='{ "from" : "bqvieybn", "where": "{3.EX.18}"}';`.

Comment: Thanks alot Sir Nathan. You are the best

Comment: @NathanHawe, one more question, let assume that I want to delete records where two variables matches **Eg. where record ID is 18 and email address is ann@gmail.**  How do I do that. Between Thanks, hoping to hear from you sir

Comment: @NancyMooree, you can pass any query as the value for the the `where` property and all the records that match your query will be deleted.  So, assuming that email is field ID #8 your query might look like `{3.EX.18}AND{8.EX.'ann@gmail.com'}`.  You can read more about Quick Base's query syntax on their [Components of a Query](https://help.quickbase.com/api-guide/componentsquery.html) page.  This is the same syntax used to query records so you can double check which records you're about to delete by plugging that query into a get records request.

Comment: @NathanHawe. Thanks alot

Comment: @NathanHawe Please I need your help at this issue here on stackoverflow.Thanks link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64513539/issues-with-quickbase-api-call