# Issues with Quickbase API call

Tags: quickbase

I am using JSON Quickbase API documentation below:

[Quickbase API](https://developer.quickbase.com/operation/upsert)

I am trying to update records with Quickbase via recordId as per below, and it's working fine:

```
{
  "to": "my-table-id-goes-here",
  "data": [
    {


      "6": {
        "value": "nancy more is the value to be updated"
      },

"3": {
        "value": "recordId_to_be_used_to_make_updates"
      }

    }
  ]
  
}
```

**My issue:** I want to update where **email** and **userid** is equal to certain value.

Eg. in normal SQL queries something like `"update mytable_name set name ='nancy more' where email='nancy@gmail.com' and userid=70"`.

Is it possible with Quickbase? Is there a way to achieve that based on the code above, assuming **email field is 7** and **userid field is 8** or whatever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The end result is possible but not through a single API call.  The insert/update records API call for Quick Base only updates records when the key field is included in the record payload (the key field is the record ID by default but can be changed to another field in the table).  If you don't already know the value of the key field, you'll need to query for the matching records first and then use the returned record ID/key field to perform that update.

For example, you could query for records where email is "nancy@gmail.com" and userid is 70:

```
POST https://api.quickbase.com/v1/records/query
QB-Realm-Hostname: host
Authorization: QB-USER-TOKEN userToken
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "from": "tableId",
    "where": "{7.EX.'nancy@gmail.com'}AND{8.EX.70}"
}
```

You can then use the id's of the returned set of records to perform your update.  How you go about reading the response and making the upsert request will depend on the language you're using.

Comment: Thanks alot sir. God Bless You.

Comment: Hello Sir @NathanHawe  I hope you are doing fine. Please Sir, can you help me out with this. Thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64526230/how-to-properly-perform-like-queries-with-quick-table