# How to properly perform like queries with Quickbase

Tags: quickbase

I am working with quicktable queries and everything seems to be fine.

Now I want to perform queries using like operators. For instance in PHP I can do something like:

```
$data ='content to search';

$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM members where name like :name OR email like :email limit 20');
$stmt->execute(array(
':name' => '%'.$data.'%',
':email' => '%'.$data.'%',
));
```

Now in quick table, I have tried using **CT, EX or HAS** parameter etc with **OR** Operators. Only **CT** gives nearby result but not exact as per code below.

```
//Email = 7
//name =8

{
    "from": "tableId",
    "where": "{7.CT.'nancy@gmail.com'}OR{8.CT.'nancy'}"
}
```

Is there any way I can obtain a better search with like operators with Quickbase. The [documentation here](https://help.quickbase.com/api-guide/do_query.html) does not cover that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CT` is the closest string comparison operator in Quick Base to `LIKE` in SQL, but since you can't use wildcards in Quick Base queries you might need to group multiple query strings to achieve the same result. The is also a `SW` operator that can sometimes come in helpful for comparing parts of a strings.

Comment: SW is also okay but CT seems to be the best option. I brings out my result out of loop and is working great. Thank you. Am also upvoting it as the best answer so far